# Does ADAPTIVE Communication Environment (ACE) C++ library has support for iOS and Android?

Tags: c++, android-networking, ace

I have been searching for cross platform C++ networking libraries with SSL and authentication support and came across ADAPTIVE Communication Environment (ACE) C++ library.

However, searching through its website ( http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html and http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ACE-versions-i.html), i can't find android mentioned anywhere.

Is this library supported on Android along with MacOS, Windows and Linux? I have also come across boost ASIO and POCO but wanted to consider ACE as well if the platform support is there for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

ACE supports Android and iOS, see the [ACE-INSTALL.html](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/blob/master/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html) for some documentation.